# jQuery - onClick open random links in new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This code is woking after 5sec on click this open the link in a new page, but I want to do now is to at radom links, so i want to add 5 links, someone can help me to show me how i can add more links here ? thanks

```
    $(document).click(function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
            window.focus();
        }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you .

```
var textArray = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.facebook.com','https://www.yahoo.com','https://www.twitter.com'];
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*textArray.length);
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.open(textArray[randomNumber ], '_blank');
        window.focus();
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Yes this works, Thank You.